# How to read Binary Data from Serial Port without any Encoding?

Tags: c#, matlab, serial-port

I have developed an application to read data from SerialPort in C#. Its working fine. But the data read from SerialPort is different than I expected.

When I read the port using XCTU or Matlab it will gives the data like the following,

```
00 00 e2 00 40 74 95 07 02 25 14 00 8a 92 00 77 ff
```

But When I am reading the same data from C# application it gives,

```
8C3F275A483F
```

I am expecting the result data of C# application like the result from Matlab and XCTU. I have tried with SerialPort encodings(ASCIIEncoding, Unicode, Latin). But nothing works. Help me. this is my code,

```
//DataReceived event handler
public event EventHandler<SerialDataEventArgs> NewSerialDataRecieved;
//Serial Port Initialization
SerialPort _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3",9600,Parity.None,8,StopBits.One);
_serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(_serialPort_DataReceived);
_serialPort.Open();

//DataReceived event
void _serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    int dataLength = _serialPort.BytesToRead;
    byte[] data = new byte[dataLength];
    int nbrDataRead = _serialPort.Read(data, 0, dataLength);
    if (nbrDataRead == 0)
        return;

    if (NewSerialDataRecieved != null)
        NewSerialDataRecieved(this, new SerialDataEventArgs(data));
}

//class SerialDataEventArgs
public class SerialDataEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Data;
    public SerialDataEventArgs(string dataInByteArray)
    {
        Data = dataInByteArray;
    }

}

//printing the read data
string str = BitConverter.ToString(e.Data);
txtData.AppendText(str);//txtData is a TextBox
```

Comment: 1. You posted two examples of data: are they the same data read by the two different programs?   2. What device are you trying to read? Does the device have documentation as to what it is sending you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is constructing a `System.String` instance from a byte array, which will attempt to form a valid text value from the bytes using the default encoding, whatever that happens to be on your system.

Either you need to change your `SerialDataEventArgs` class to use `byte[]` instead of `string` or convert the byte array to a string of hex digits using `BitConverter.ToString(data)` or similar.  Something like:

```
//class SerialDataEventArgs
public class SerialDataEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Data;
    public SerialDataEventArgs(byte dataInByteArray)
    {
        Data = BitConverter.ToString(dataInByteArray).Replace("-", " ");
    }
}
```

That will give you the hex values of the bytes, with each byte separated by spaces.  Personally I think that loses some utility.... much better to do that conversion from a byte array if you want to write the data to the screen for the user to view but keep it as a byte array for actual data processing.

Comment: thank you Corey, i have tried this but it gives the data like 8C3F275A483F. Actually am reading a rfid card using rfid card reader, it gives like 00 00 e2 00 40 74 95 07 02 25 14 00 8a 92 00 77 ff when am reading it with matlab, while reading the same card with my c# app, it will gives the output like 8C3F275A483F. I can't understand the relation between these two data. Matlab gives raw data, it need this raw data from my c# app, is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you confirm that the data buffer contains the bytes `8C 3F 27 5A 48 3F` after the read?  If so then there may be a problem with your serial port initialization code.  Check the data rate and framing bits... if the card reader is sending 8N1 at 9600 baud and you're receiving some other format or data rate that could explain the different received data.